# Trying to find a mass function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> I've got   $Q$ , a vector in $\Bbb R^2$ such that every Coordinate of $Q$, is with standard normal distribution, $N(0,1)$, independently. Let $S$ be the area of the circle, that $(0,0)$ is the centre of, and $Q$ is directly on the circle.
>   I need to find the mass function of $S$.

So first of all, I tried to find the radius of the circle, 
so I came up with this stuff:

$$\large r^2 = {{\left(\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)}^2 + \left({\frac{e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\right)}^2$$

$$\implies r= \sqrt{\frac{e^{-x^2} + e^{-y^2}}{2\pi}}$$

and finally:

$$F_s(x,y) = {\frac{e^{-x^2} + e^{-y^2}}{2}}$$

Now is it true that:

$$f_s(x,y) = {\frac{-e^{-x^2}2x -2ye^{-y^2}}{2}}$$

is it true? thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the statement/question: $Q$ is a random vector, and $S$ is a random variable (here, the area of a disk) defined by the realization of $Q$?

Comment: Q is a point on $R^2$ such that it's Cartesian coordinates (x,y) have a standard normal distribution.